# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser find direct LI elements

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li><a></a>
  <ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  ...
 </li>
</ul>
```

For parent `ul:first-of-type`, what would be the selector for it's (direct) child  `li` elements, in order to parse the descendant `li` elements separately?

Comment: @Gordon: I don't really understand why this question was put as off-topic. It's clear what I want to achieve, even got an answer.

Comment: It was closed because it didn't **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** In particular, you do not explain what you have tried to solve this problem or why the documentation at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm didn't help. We expect you to do thorough research before asking. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: I did read the documentation, but thought there is some other way to do so: something like "li not li li". The information I found was as below, but it wasn't complete solution, as there were other elements in ul than li, but... as it is not valid html, I accepted the answer below.

Comment: Well, the point is: you didn't include that information in your question, when our [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Ask Advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) asks you to. Always include what you have tried and researched, so people can see you are not a lazy help vampire. I am releasing the question from on-hold now, but please keep it in mind for your future questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Jquery you can simply use this selector : `ul > li`

**Update:-**

Using Simple DOM:-

```
<ul class="listitems">
 <li><a></a>
  <ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  ...
 </li>
</ul>
```

Simple HTML Dom code to get just the first level li items:

```
$html = file_get_html( $url );
$first_level_items = $html->find( '.listitems', 0)->children();

foreach ( $first_level_items as $item ) {
    ... do stuff ...
}
```

Comment: Note that SimpleHtmlDom doesnt support `>`. See http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm